# How can I get a counter-clockwise loop with the TikZ automata package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

Using

```
\draw [->] (2) to[loop above] node[auto] {$\beta_2$} (2);
```

I get "clockwise" loop. Is it possible to get a counter-clockwise loop?

Comment: If I may be so bold: if my answer solved your problem, would you consider accepting it?

Comment: Sorry, @TorbjørnT., I got involved with another project and hadn't got around to testing your answer. It works well; thank you for the multiple suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw](2){?};
\draw [->] (2) edge[in=100,out=80,loop] node[above] {$\beta_2$} (2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw](2){?} edge[in=100,out=80,loop] node[above] {$\beta_2$}();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way is to change the `every loop` style. By default this is `->,shorten >=1pt`, if you change it to `<-,shorten <=1pt`, the arrow is turned around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every loop/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt}]
\node[circle,draw](2){?} edge[loop above] node[above] {$\beta_2$}();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]